# get all solutions (2 unknowns) from fsolve in python 3.2

Tags: python, windows-7, python-3.2

I need to get all solutions (2 unknowns) from fsolve in python 3.2.

But, it only returns one event though I have set full_output = true in fsolve.

```
def integrand1(x, b, c):
   return (x/b)**(c-1) * exp(-x/b)

def intergralFunc2(b):
   integral,err = quad(integrand2, 0, 100, args=(b))
   return 100 - integral

def solveFunction():
   sol= fsolve(intergralFunc1, 5, 5, full_output=True)
   return sol

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sol = solveFunction()
    print("sol is ", sol)
```

I need to know the solution for b and c, but, fsolve() only returns solution for b.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `fmin` (see the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin.html#scipy.optimize.fmin)) instead of `fsolve` and changing `integralFunc` so that it takes a sequence containing `b` and `c` and returns `abs(100 - integral)` will get both parameters.

```
from scipy.integrate import quad
from scipy.optimize import fmin

def integrand(x, b, c):
   return (x/b)**(c-1) * exp(-x/b)

def intergralFunc(bc):
   integral,err = quad(integrand, 0, 100, args=(bc[0], bc[1]))
   return abs(100 - integral)

def solveFunction():
   sol= fmin(intergralFunc, [5, 5])
   return sol

b, c = solveFunction()
```

Output:

```
Optimization terminated successfully.
         Current function value: 0.000000
         Iterations: 49
         Function evaluations: 89
```

Checking `b` and `c`

```
>>> integral, err = quad(integrand, 0, 100, args=(b, c))
>>> np.allclose(100, integral)
True
```

**EDIT:**

If you *have* to use `fsolve`, this will work since `fsolve` expects the shape output of the objective function to be the same same as the input, but you will get slightly different results for `b` and `c` than if you use `fmin`.  I get `b, c = (4.48517289097, 4.95091626134)` with `fsolve` and `b, c = (5.14997777422, 4.85783682022)` with `fmin`

```
def intergralFunc(bc):
   integral,err = quad(integrand, 0, 100, args=(bc[0], bc[1]))
   return np.array([100 - integral] * 2)

def solveFunction():
   sol= fsolve(intergralFunc, [5, 5])
   return sol
```